# Garbage Collection app loading ARC binary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, memory-management, garbage-collection

As we know, programming objective-c in X-code used to mean handling manual reference counting of objects. Following this, garbage collection was introduced and this has now been superseded by automatic reference counting (ARC).

In the past, I've had an application developed with GC which could load libraries using the function call dlopen. This required that the loading library matched that of the host application and also used GC. If the library was built with ARC, dlopen would fail. Naturally, this incompatibility is to be expected.

The System Preferences application is a good example here. It uses garbage collection: -

```
otool -oV /Applications/System\ Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Preferences | tail -3
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_imageinfo) section
version 0
flags 0x2 OBJC_IMAGE_SUPPORTS_GC
```

Up until 10.7 [so did the preference panes which it loads](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Articles/UpdatingPreferencePanes.html). However, in 10.8 the System Preferences application still uses GC, but some of the panes which it loads do not: -

```
otool -oV /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Network.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/Network | tail -3
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_imageinfo) section
  version 0
    flags 0x0
```

So, what's going on here? How does the garbage collection mechanism of the System Preferences application handle the ARC-compiled panes? Do they just leak the memory, or is there some sort of conversion going on underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC does not change the rule you're familiar with, garbage collection must still be enabled or disabled for the entire process.

To understand how System Preferences works, take a closer look at the flags from `__objc_imageinfo`. Here are the [Clang definitions](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CGObjCMac.cpp?revision=208382&view=markup#l4268) for those flags:

```
enum ImageInfoFlags {
  eImageInfo_FixAndContinue      = (1 << 0), // This flag is no longer set by clang.
  eImageInfo_GarbageCollected    = (1 << 1),
  eImageInfo_GCOnly              = (1 << 2),
  eImageInfo_OptimizedByDyld     = (1 << 3), // This flag is set by the dyld shared cache.

  // A flag indicating that the module has no instances of a @synthesize of a
  // superclass variable. <rdar://problem/6803242>
  eImageInfo_CorrectedSynthesize = (1 << 4), // This flag is no longer set by clang.
  eImageInfo_ImageIsSimulated    = (1 << 5)
};
```

The 10.8+ version of System Preferences has the garbage collected flag set but not the GC-only flag. This means that it was built with -fobjc-gc and includes code to support both garbage collection and retain/release. As a result it can be run with GC either enabled or disabled via the `OBJC_DISABLE_GC` environment variable. Looking at the Info.plist for System Preferences this is exactly what it does:

```
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
    <key>OBJC_DISABLE_GC</key>
    <string>YES</string>
</dict>
```

With this combination System Preferences launches with garbage collection disabled, and can load preference panes without GC support and those built with both GC and retain/release support via -fobjc-gc. If the user tries to open a preference pane that requires garbage collection (built with -fobjc-gc-only) System Preferences informs the user that it needs to restart to load that pane. If permission is granted the app relaunches itself with OBJC_DISABLE_GC=NO. At this point it can load preference panes that require GC support and those built with both GC and retain/release support. If the user subsequently tries to load a preference pane without GC support the app will need to relaunch again.

So there's no GC and non-GC magic here, just a backwards-compatibility mechanism made possible by the System Preferences UI not requiring that all preference panes be loaded at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

ARC ***is*** actually backward compatible with libraries and frameworks compiled under non-ARC, so mixing ARC code with non-ARC code is not that unusual. The way it works is by using a flag at compile time to switch ARC on/off:

```
-fno-objc-arc
-fobjc-arc
```

For example, you can set the target to build default as ARC, and for the code that isn't ARC you'll be able to switch to a non-ARC compiler during that particular build phase.

Obviously there's much more to it than just what I've mentioned, but at least you know it's very possible to mix non-ARC with ARC.

Comment: Arc is backward compatible with manual reference counting, but not GC, as I understand it. "With Apple's garbage collector, either the entire application runs under GC, or none of it does" - https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html

Comment: @Merlin069, How else would you explain the otool output? If GC cannot co-exist with ARC then there's no mention of that anywhere within Apple's documentation (that I've seen); They do point out that GC[¹](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSGarbageCollector_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) is deprecated and that ARC[²](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) should be used moving forward; I'm not really sure why anyone would want to use both anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you're misunderstanding me. I know it works, as can be seen from System Preferences and the otool output. However, if the application is using garbage collection for memory management, what does it do when it encounters a dynamic library's code that isn't GC'd? I'm not asking how to enable the feature, but from an academic view, what is going on at run-time?

Comment: Yes, I presumed you were asking to gain an understanding of how it's working. Are you asking specifically what would happen to the GC compiled library if it encountered an ARC compiled library? ARC is able to co-exist simply because it's permitted (at times) to optimize `release` operations; it doesn't rely on stack scanning atomicity, but rather the semantics of optimization within objects. How a GC based application would handle any non-GC dynamic library depends on many factors. I would imagine existing with ARC there wouldn't be any guarantee if undefined computations, etc. were present.